# Save gif to camera roll in cordova app

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cordova, gif

I am trying to save an animated gif to the phone's camera roll from a cordova app.

I am able to draw the gif to a `<canvas>` and save it using the [Canvas2Image](https://github.com/devgeeks/Canvas2ImagePlugin). But the `<canvas>` tag does not support animation so all that is saved is an image.

Any advice or help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have tried the above and https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-save-to-photoalbum